# Insertion of data in postgesSQL using python facing

Tags: python, postgresql

I have created a table in postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE "DataSource"(
  src_id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  src_name character varying(20),
  password character varying(25),
  host character varying(30),
  created_date date,
  user_name character varying(30),
  src_type character varying(15),
  db_name character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  port numeric(32,0),
  CONSTRAINT "DataSource_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (src_id, db_name)
)
```

And also created a method in python for inserting the in the above table:

```
def insertDataSource(srcName, srcType ,owner, src_password, location, creationDate,db_name,port_no='DEFAULT'):
    srcId=idGeneratorforData(srcName)# idGeneratorforData() method generate a id string value 
    conn = get_connect()
    if conn:
         cur = conn.cursor()#cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    else:
         print "Failed to connect..."
    cur.execute('''insert into "DataSource"("src_id","user_name","src_name","created_date","src_type","password","host", "db_name", "port") values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')''' %(srcId,owner,srcName,creationDate,srcType, src_password, location, db_name, port_no))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Now when i try to call this method as

```
insertDataSource("postgres", "Structured", "postgres", "root", "localhost", "12-10-2015", "postgres", "5432")
```

Then it throws a TypeError::

```
cur.execute('''insert into "DataSource"("src_id","user_name","src_name","created_date","src_type","password","host", "db_name", "port") values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')''' %(srcId,owner,srcName,creationDate,srcType, src_password, location, db_name, port_no))
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I have also tried to pass a DEFAULT value for the port number, the code still throw the same error, but when i have fired the same query through SQL prompt.. it works.

i am not able to understand why this problem occur..., the same code is working fine from before today...

Comment: You have nine column names but only eight `%s'`s.

Comment: Thanx John Gordon.....

Comment: port_no in numeric type, so what will be the default value of the port no?